# Laravel 5.2: retrieving a cookie via blade returns null also if cookie is set

Tags: cookies, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I set a cookie `my_cookie` via Javascript

```
   function createCookie(name, value, days) {
      var expires;
      if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toUTCString();
      }
      else {
        expires = "";
      }
      document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
   }

   ....
   createCookie('my_cookie', 1, 365);
   ....
```

Via Chrome Cookie Inspector I see that the cookie is created with value 1.

Via Laravel Blade I tried:

```
 @if (Cookie::get('my_cookie') !== null) // or Cookie::get('my_cookie') == 1 or Cookie::get('my_cookie') == '1'
      <p>set</p>
 @else
      <p>unset</p>
 @endif
```

that writes `unset`

```
 @if (request()->cookie('my_cookie') == '1') // or @if (request()->cookie('my_cookie') == 1)
      <p>set</p>
 @else
      <p>unset</p>
 @endif
```

The result is always `unset`.

Comment: Only cookie created by laravel can handle by laravel. Try native cookie `$_COOKIE`. Or try create cookie by laravel then `dd($_COOKIE)` you'll understand why

Comment: @KmasterYC: Thanks. If you transform your comment in answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Ok. I move now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Move from comment**: Only cookie created by laravel can handle by laravel. Try native cookie $_COOKIE. Or try create cookie by laravel then dd($_COOKIE) you'll see it totally different to cookie which created by native PHP

Answer (score 61):

You can use

`App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies`'s field `$except` for your needs.

The code of the middleware will look like this

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies as BaseEncrypter;

class EncryptCookies extends BaseEncrypter
{
  /**
   * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
   *
   * @var array
   */
   protected $except = [
      'my_cookie'
   ];
}
```

And now you can use `Cookie::get('my_cookie')` or `request()->cookie('my_cookie')` for retrieving it

Comment: wow, I spent a lot of time for this one thanks. Strange there is no info in docs about this.

Comment: should be approved answer :clap:

Answer (score 9):

It's because laravel encrypts their cookies. You can just not include `EncryptCookies` middleware to work with cookies, which weren't being set by laravel. Remove `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class` from `$middlewareGroups` in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

Comment: So when you encrypt cookie, it wont be accessible to Laravel ? :P Pretty funny, then why do we use Laravel?