# Why cookie of laravel is null - 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

my cookie is null! But I don't know :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
```

HomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    Cookie::queue('currentLang', 'heb', 999999999);



      $cat1         = $this->categoryRepo->findCategoryById(1);
      $lastPosts    = $this->blogPosts->listBlogPosts(array('*'),'id','desc')->take(3);

    return view('front.index', compact('cat1','lastPosts'));
}
```

now I want to get this key from another controller:

LoginController:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    dd(Cookie::get('currentLang'));
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

but it returns null !
I'm working on localhost.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052612/laravel-5-2-retrieving-a-cookie-via-blade-returns-null-also-if-cookie-is-set might  help you. Issue might be due to cookie encryption by laravel

Comment: `Cookie::queue(...` is used to attach a cookie to your response(an alternative), per the docs. If you inspect the response headers you should notice that `Set-Cookie: currentLang=someencryptedvalue` does indeed exist. Also, since you created the cookie with Laravel, Laravel knows how to retrieve this cookie, the issue is not due to encryption.

Answer (score 0):

`Cookie::queue(...` is used to attach a cookie to your response(an alternative), per the docs. If you inspect the response headers you should notice that `Set-Cookie: currentLang=someencryptedvalue` does indeed exist.

I have created some prototype endpoints to illustrate creating and deleting cookies:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

Route::get('/wont-clear-cookie', function() {
    Cookie::forget('currentLang');

    return redirect()->to('/get-cookie');
});

Route::get('/clear-cookie', function() {
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('currentLang'));

    return redirect()->to('/get-cookie');
});

Route::get('/set-cookie', function() {
    Cookie::queue('currentLang', 'heb', 999999999);

    return redirect()->to('/get-cookie');
});

Route::get('/get-cookie', function() {
    dump(Cookie::get('currentLang'));
    dd(request()->cookie('currentLang'));
});
```

The above endpoints should be placed in `web.php`.

Also, Make sure your `web` middleware group is configured correctly in `App\Http\Kernal.php`:

```
'web' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

Comment: it returns `nul` value.

Comment: make sure your routes are inside your web middleware group, and that the middleware group `web` is configured correctly.